# Install specific version of package using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to install `pexpect` using Ansible.
I am using `ansible.builtin.package` module. But old version is getting installed. I need `pexpect` version >=3.3.

How can I achieve that using this module?

Comment: Use `pip`. The version of pexpect you will get from an OS package depends on the state of that package in the repository of package of the OS, so if it is at version X.Z, then, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using Fedora 35 as example, the syntax is `<package_name>-<package_version>`.

In this example I'm using **ansible ad-hoc** command for installing version `4.8.0-6.fc35` of the `screen` package. You have to replace `<hostname>` with the host you want to update.

```sh
ansible <hostname> -m package -a "name=screen-4.8.0-6.fc35 state=present" --become -K
```

The result of such command is.

```
hostname | CHANGED => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "",
    "rc": 0,
    "results": [
        "Installed: screen-4.8.0-6.fc35.x86_64"
    ]
}
```